# How can display a component on click button in React Hooks?

Tags: axios, react-hooks

I fetch an employee data from API using AXOIS and display it in HTML table and I add it a button that shows extra information in another component, the problem is when I click on  the button it renders the component in all line for example if have two employees in the table and I want to display more information about the first employees in the table the component will appear in both line
the component that fetches to data :

```
          componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(('http://localhost:5000/api/findEmployee'),
         { headers: {
         "Content-type": "application/json"
          }}).
        then(response =>{ 
          this.setState({employeeData:response.data }) ;
                    console.log(response.data);
                  }

         )

     .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
            }



           <Table  employeeData={this.state.employeeData}/>
```

the TAble Component

```
     import React,{useState} from 'react';
    import  EmployeeCard from '../postEmployeeCard';
    const Table = ({employeeData}) => {
    const [showComponent , setShowComponet]=useState(false);

    function onButtonClick(value){
    setShowComponet(true);
    ;



 setVal1(value1);

    } 
    return (
      <table>
       <head>
        <tr>
         <th></th>  
      <th>FirstName </th>  
      <th>LAstName</th>
      <th>Registration Number</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  { (employeeData.length > 0) ? employeeData.map( (employee , index) => {
       return (
        <tr key={index}>


             <td><button  value= {employee}  onClick={() =>onButtonClick(employee)}> Show </button>
            {showComponent ? <EmployeeCard props={employee}[enter image description here][1]/> : null}
            </td>

          <td>{employee.PhoneNumber }</td>
          <td>{employee.LastName }</td>
          <td>{employee.FirstName }</td>
          <td>{employee.RegistrationNumber}</td>


         </tr>

      )
     }) : <tr><td colSpan="5">Loading...</td></tr> }
  </tbody>
</table>
        );
       }
       export default Table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use one variable for all rows. To solve your problem, you can write a separate component:

```
const TRow = ({
  index,
  employee
}) => {
  const [showComponent, setShowComponet]=useState(false);
  const onButtonClick = () =>
    setShowComponet(true);

  return <tr key={index}>
    <td><button  value= {employee}  onClick={() =>onButtonClick(employee)}> Show </button>
      {showComponent ? <EmployeeCard props={employee}[enter image description here][1]/> : null}
     </td>
     <td>{employee.PhoneNumber }</td>
     <td>{employee.LastName }</td>
     <td>{employee.FirstName }</td>
     <td>{employee.RegistrationNumber}</td>
   </tr>
}
```

.......

```
{ (employeeData.length > 0) ? employeeData.map((employee, i) =>
   <Trow employee={ employee } index={ i } />)
   : <tr><td colSpan="5">Loading...</td></tr> }
```